# How can I write a shell script that goes into a screen and invokes something?

Tags: shell, gnu-screen

My IRC bot sporadically dies sometimes and I have it in a screen. The way to invoke it again is `node protobot.js`.

I have to always find that screen and reinvoke it. I'd like a faster way.

How can I invoke screen reliably from within a shell script in order to invoke node to revive it?

Comment: Please see [Process Management](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessManagement#How_can_I_check_to_see_if_my_game_server_is_still_running.3F__I.27ll_put_a_script_in_crontab.2C_and_if_it.27s_not_running.2C_I.27ll_restart_it...).

Answer (score 2):

Your process needs care and feeding? Do not put it in the screen to begin with.

Investigate **process monitoring**, for instance with [Monit](http://mmonit.com/monit/), or [God](http://god.rubyforge.org/), or some other keep-it-alive software. There are tons of alternatives. When you've seen these two, the Net should provide you with pros and cons and other names of software.